# Batchfile to create backup and rename with timestamp

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-vista

I have the following network path to copy the file to an archive folder. It copies `File 1` from `Folder` to `Archive` but I would like to add these 2 adjustments that won't work.

1. Rename `File 1-1` to `File 1 - date + time`
2. Running it now displays a cmd box with the copy code, is it possible
   to run it in the background or have a loading screen to show the
   progress?

For my code I followed [this example](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000987.htm) to change the name to a date.

```
copy "F:\Folder\File 1.xlsx" "F:\Folder\Archive\File 1-1.xlsx"
/f "tokens=1-5 delim s=/ " %%d in ("%date%") do rename "F:\Folder example 2.xlsx" "F:\Folder\File example %%e-%%f-%%g.xlsx"
```

Answer (score 32):

try this:

```
ren "File 1-1" "File 1 - %date:/=-% %time::=-%"
```

Comment: Does this need any extra documentation, or is it enough to use only this?

Comment: Oh, win so hard. This is the most elegant straightforward way to do it using Windows environment variables like `%DATE%` and `%TIME%`. Thanks! Awesome.

Comment: My answers are valid only for a specific question.

Comment: Using only %DATE% will output / within the date string, which caused problems in my path. Using %date:/=-% replaced the / with - characters and my path worked.

Comment: Yes, please check my code. DATE also depends on local settings.

Comment: 8 years later and I still use it!

Comment: I chose the code @foxidrive had because it takes the time stamp and safes it. Why is that a good thing? Because if you apply the time stamp to the file as it is being saved then each file will have a different time, seconds. So if you are backing up several files and want to keep the as a set and then you do a search, all you have to do is look for several different time stamps instead of just one.

Answer (score 28):

See if this is what you want to do:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a
set YYYY=%dt:~0,4%
set MM=%dt:~4,2%
set DD=%dt:~6,2%
set HH=%dt:~8,2%
set Min=%dt:~10,2%
set Sec=%dt:~12,2%

set stamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%

copy "F:\Folder\File 1.xlsx" "F:\Folder\Archive\File 1 - %stamp%.xlsx"
```

Comment: 6 years later and I used it.

Comment: This solution has the benefit of putting the most significant part of the date first in the new file name, so year comes before month which comes before day. (Which means files sorted in name order are also sorted in date order.) And it is independent of the locale. If you put all commands except the copy command in a batch file, you can run this and then have multiple copy runs all with the same date and time.

Comment: @finch Adding that putting the Date and Time stamp BEFORE the file name will group the files together by date first. Otherwise You will have a bunch of files starting with "A" and then a bunch of file starting with "B", then you have to find and select the ones that have the same date. Hope it makes sense. Applies to backing up multiple files. Even so it still is better.

Answer (score 11):

I've modified Foxidrive's answer to copy entire folders and all their contents. 
this script will create a folder and backup another folder's contents into it, including any subfolders underneath.

If you put this in say an hourly scheduled task you need to be careful as you could fill up your drive quickly with copies of your original folder. Before bitbucket etc i was using as similar script to save my code offline.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a
set YYYY=%dt:~0,4%
set MM=%dt:~4,2%
set DD=%dt:~6,2%
set HH=%dt:~8,2%
set Min=%dt:~10,2%
set Sec=%dt:~12,2%

set stamp=YourPrefixHere_%YYYY%%MM%%DD%@%HH%%Min%
rem you could for example want to create a folder in Gdrive and save backup there
cd C:\YourGoogleDriveFolder
mkdir %stamp%
cd %stamp%

 xcopy C:\FolderWithDataToBackup\*.* /s
```

Answer (score 2):

Renames all `.pdf` files based on current system date.  For example a file named `Gross Profit.pdf` is renamed to `Gross Profit 2014-07-31.pdf`.  If you run it tomorrow, it will rename it to `Gross Profit 2014-08-01.pdf`.

You could replace the `?` with the report name `Gross Profit`, but it will only rename the one report.  The `?` renames everything in the `Conduit` folder.  The reason there are so many `?`, is that some `.pdf`s have long names.   If you just put 12 `?`s, then any name longer than 12 characters will be clipped off at the 13th character.  Try it with 1 `?`, then try it with many `?`s.  The `?` length should be a little longer or as long as the longest report name.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET NETWORKSOURCE=\\flcorpfile\shared\"SHORE Reports"\2014\Conduit
REN %NETWORKSOURCE%\*.pdf "????????????????????????????????????????????????? %date:~-4,4%-%date:~-10,2%-%date:~7,2%.pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to make it run in the background create a shortcut to the batch file and go into the properties. I'm on a Linux machine ATM but I believe the option you are wanting is in the advanced tab.

You can also run your batch script through a vbs script like this:

```
'HideBat.vbs
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "your_batch_file.bat", 0, True
```

This will execute your batch file with no cmd window shown.