# Batch - Error when renaming a file to timestamp

Tags: batch-file

I have a program that takes EVERYTHING from the directory 
C:\Users\Hensel\Desktop\mc-server\world, and it then it copies and pastes it in a separate directory 
C:\Users\Hensel\Desktop\backups\

Then it renames the file called 'world' that it copied and renames it to a date/timestamp format.

```
@echo off
:backup
xcopy C:\Users\Hensel\Desktop\mc-server\world C:\Users\Hensel\Desktop\backups\world /I /E /Y /D
ren world Logs-%date:~10,4%%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%
ping localhost -n 2700 >nul
goto backup
```

But whenever I run it (I execute it within the backups directory), it returns the error of: "The syntax of the command is incorrect." Whenever I remove the line that renames 'world' it works fine, but the files won't have unique names when they are backed up unless it has a date and timestamp.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Batchfile to create backup and rename with timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17996936/batchfile-to-create-backup-and-rename-with-timestamp)

Comment: Works fine on my Windows 7 box. What's the current directorhy when you are executing this command? Is it your backup folder?

Comment: @Laf Yes, it is executed from the backups folder.

Comment: Put `echo ren` in the command and you will see if any spaces or poison characters are in the text.

Comment: There is something i don't understand, what are you renaming? if as said, it is run from your backup folder, `world` is a directory (the target to xcopy) but you say you rename a file called 'world' to `.. whatever .. .txt`. Is this a file called `world` inside the target folder `world`? Or are you trying to rename the folder?

Comment: @MCND I am trying to copy all of the contents of one folder, then take all the contents of the folder and put it in a file titled the current date and time.

Comment: @DawsonH: by "take all the contents of the folder and put it in a file" you mean the file contains a list of the files in the folder or that the file contains all data inside the folder?

Comment: @MCND The final file output shouldn't have .txt, that was a typo. No, the actual files themselves are in a folder called 'world'. I need to move them to a separate folder, 'backups', and in that folder, 'world' will need to be renamed to current date and time so that all the folders won't be named the same thing and overwrite each other. I need access to all of these backups for later use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing your exact date/time format, I'd judge that you have spaces in the new filename.

try

```
set "newname=Logs-%date:~10,4%%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%.txt"
set newname=%newname: =0%
ren world %newname%
```

and if that doesn't work (which it should) then tell us what happens with

```
echo newname="%newname%"
```

which should be inserted just before the `REN`

---

So the full new file should be:

```
@echo off
:backup
xcopy C:\Users\Hensel\Desktop\mc-server\world C:\Users\Hensel\Desktop\backups\world /I /E /Y /D
set "newname=Logs-%date:~10,4%%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%.txt"
set newname=%newname: =0%
ren world %newname%
echo newname="%newname%"
ping localhost -n 2700 >nul
goto backup
```

where the `echo newname="%newname%"` line is optional

Meanwhile, in place of your `PING` line, you could try

```
timeout /t 2700 >nul
```

for a 45-minute delay in an "approved" manner.

Comment: Can you show me what the entire new file should look like? I'm not sure where to insert the code you posted.

Comment: Hmm. It seems that it just opens and closes. Doesn't seem to be working. I'll try and see what the problem is.